# How to know if a position is on the road or on the sidewalk?

Tags: android, gps, position, maps

is there any way that I can get what kind of point (lat/long) I'm getting, I mean if the location I'm asking is in the middle of the road or on a sidewalk?
Don't care if it is OpenStreet maps o Google maps, I think the google maps api has something like this but I think unless you pay for the service it is not recommended.

Comment: feels too fine grained to be possible to me.

Comment: Given that the best accuracy you will get is around a metre and often in the order of 3 metres, no!

Comment: @Simon He did not wrote, that the location was obtained by GPS. A location can be precise up to milimeters.

Comment: I doubt that you will get a bette ranswer, but in the mean time you should consider upvoting, since the approach would work having precise coordinates, and will work for most streets in europe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible if you have the vector data of all roads.

But this is not a fast to implement and cheap way.

If you get the locations with a standard GPS receiver, then the position is not precise enough (around 2,5m on average but sometime sup to 30m) and usuallay the coordinates of the road vector is not precise enough, too.

However to determine between a road where vehicle drive and a sidewalk nearby where only pedestrians walk, you can distuinguish by the `speed` attribute of the (GPS) location.

If speed < 7 then walking on sidewalk.
if speed > 15 the driving on road.

And check the direction of the road, to match the GPS direction.

But I give you the tipp, forget that. It's very likely that the result is not good enough for the (whatever) application needs.

Comment: How would having the vectors help if the GPS accuracy is not good enough?

Comment: Updated answer, the GPS accuracy is to low, but via speed it coul dbe decided between pedestrains and vehciles, which do not share the same road.

Comment: Hmmm, you've never been to India ;)

Comment: Better upvote my answer, and take the tip, to forget that task. ;-)